# Firestore Query Help (Compound Queries)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I'm building a scholarship matching engine and have most of the matching working, at least the fields that are strings.

I have numeric input fields such as GPA and SAT in the user details. I want to match scholarships that meet the criteria of these numeric fields in addition to the strings. Firebase compound queries only support filters on the same field at a time.

CODE:

```
and(
  where(
    "matchCriteriaValuesArray",
    "array-contains-any",
    userAllFieldsValue
  ),
  or(
    where("gpa-Min", "<=", user?.gpa),
    where("gpa-Max", ">=", user?.gpa)
  ),
  or(
    where("actScore-Min", "<=", user?.actScore),
    where("actScore-Max", ">=", user?.actScore)
  ),
  or(
    where("satEbrwScore-Min", "<=", user?.ebrwScore),
    where("satEbrwScore-Max", ">=", user?.ebrwScore)
  ),
  or(
    where("satMathScore-Min", "<=", user?.mathScore),
    where("satMathScore-Max", ">=", user?.mathScore)
  )
)
```

[Error Msg:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLIPl.png)
Uncaught runtime errors:
Error
Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, !=, not-in, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'gpa-Min' and 'gpa-Max'.
FirebaseError: Invalid query. All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, !=, not-in, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'gpa-Min' and 'gpa-Max'.

As a worse case workaround I was thinking I can have say GPA as a string 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 and the in the scholarship data allow a match against and array [2.5, 2.6, .. 4.0] which is okay for say a GPA but for SAT scores where a scholarship may be good for anything above a 1000, I would have string values for 1000 -> 1600 in 10pt increments.  That's rough.

Any work around ideas?  Again the string side is working with all my other criteria like city, state, school, hobbies, clubs, sports, etc.

I read the query docs, and I know there must be a way to do this but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You should copy the text of that error message into your question (as quoted text) instead of using an image.

Comment: copy the error message into the text